# unable to import jar files in GAE application

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I am creating a new web application project using the Google App Engine in Eclipse Juno 4.2.
In the Dynamic Web Projects in Eclipse i import the jar files that i require by simply copying them to the lib folder in the WEB_INF directory.

However with google app engine even after copying the jar files to lib folder of WEB_INF directory for a new web application i am still getting errors while importing libraries.
what is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I am strongly advise use the GPE plugin. Generate the appropriate project from the File->New->Google-> Choose what you want

GPE is here : https://developers.google.com/eclipse/

Comment: I am assuming that, you are going to develop an application. If you use a plugin, this simplifies your development tasks without considering lots of specific details. I think you are facing such a detail. I am using GPE. So, I did not meet such a problem.